# Mysql WHERE ... ORDER BY taking too long in large database

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, where-clause, unix-timestamp

I have a large database.
There are 22 million lines for now, but there will be billions of lines in the future.
I have attached example lines where timestamp is in milliseconds.
What I want to do is get the last line every second.

```
SELECT *
FROM   btcusdt
WHERE  1502942432000 <= timestamp
       AND timestamp < 1502942433000
ORDER  BY tradeid DESC
LIMIT  1
```

The query I wrote above works fine, but the WHERE condition takes too long because it scans all the rows in the table, but actually
It doesn't need to scan all the lines because the time is already sequential. As soon as it doesn’t fit the where condition, it should finish scanning.
Any suggestions on how I can speed this up?

[db example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwZaQ.png)

Comment: One word: indexes ;-)

Comment: I think I need more words :D

Comment: for such questions we need to see CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN ANALYSE  SELECT query

Comment: also mysql has a very good manual about that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-optimization.html

Comment: Thanks  Álvaro i add index to timestamp and its fixed